# How to test if a domestic 3 phase power company meter is reading wrong?

Tags: three-phase, earth, leakage-current, fault, meter

**BACKGROUND:**

- Domestic 3 phase 220VAC supply in Thailand.
- Power company meter is 4 wire GE 3 phase 15A/45A.
- Massive power bills when mains breakers were turned off (back in home country for 9 months due to Covid-19 travel ban) prompted investigation.
- Suspected meter fault or earth leakage.
- Power company has replaced the meter but still power usage is well above expected figures.
- Calculated figures using manufactures specs verified using a simple current clamp meter (CT not Halls) and seems to confirm the manufactures specs are pretty close to actual reading using the CT clamp meter on the LINE conductor of a modified (line/neutral/Eerth separated wires) power cord.
- Power is only being used on mainly phase 1, a little on phase 2, and NOTHING AT ALL on phase 3.
- High consumption items such as air conditioner, refrigerator/freezer, or hot water heaters are not connected at all.
- I am a robotics engineer who has a passing knowledge of 3 phase but not enough to be an expert.

**QUESTION:**

Using CT I measure the current usage and voltages for each phase line wire. I also measure the line on the 4th wire.
E.g.: I get 1A + 0.5A + 0A on each of the phases = 1.5A
I get 4.3A on the 4th wire.

The company meter is reading close to the 4.3A but the combined total of all the power-consuming items  turned on is spot on with the 1.5A read on the 3 phase line wires.

Is that normal or am I missing something?

How should I be fault finding a meter / earth leakage issue, as the power company is obviously not interested in finding a fault with their equipment?

Comment: Somebody stealing? Any odd connections? If you disconnect all your loads, does the meter still record?

Comment: @Solar Mike - thanks for your questions:
Somebody stealing (No indication found of theft so far).
Any odd connections (Nothing unusual found)
If you disconnect all your loads, does the meter still record (Suspected but seems to be too intermittent to nail it down).
Biggest concern is the over-reading when known loads are active

Comment: Try balancing load on all 3 phases and see impact on neutral.  Increase all 3 phases to 1 A.  Neutral should go to 0.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat - Thanks for joining the discussion: Ground wire should be no more than 1.5A if 1.0, 0.5 and 0 are phases. – (You are correct that those are the phase readings, and the Ground Wire is consistently more than the sum total of the phase readings)

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat - Try balancing load on all 3 phases and see impact on neutral. Increase all 3 phases to 1 A. Neutral should go to 0. – (Do you mean the 4th wire Neutral or Ground Wire should go to ZERO if all 3 phases have equal loads simultaneously?)

Comment: 4th wire neutral.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat - 4th wire neutral. – (I will test and update - What would it mean if Neutral goes to ZERO when phases are load balanced but Neutral is greater than phases sum total when load unbalanced?)

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat - 4th wire neutral. – (Also - What would it mean if Neutral DOES NOT go to ZERO when phases are load balanced AND Neutral is greater than phases sum total when load unbalanced?)

Comment: Three-phase loads are meant to be balanced. Which means neutral wire should be 0. You have current on neutral. I'd guess a load wired incorrectly.  And this is not a discussion forum.